# SQL Sum count of product by Member and product YTD of the product count

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
  DMC.MEM_NBR, 
  FIRST_NAME, 
  LAST_NAME, 
  PRODUCT_DESC, 
  DD.YEAR_MONTH AS FILL_DATE, 
  FC.PRODUCT_NBR 
  CASE 
    WHEN CAST ((CURRENT_DATE - DOB.DATE_DATE) / 365.25 as Int) >= 18  Then '18+'
    ELSE 'Less than 18'
  END MEM_AGE
FROM FT_PRODUCT_CLAIM FC
LEFT JOIN DIM_PRODUCT PRODUCT ON FC.PRODUCT_DIM_CK=PRODUCT.PRODUCT_DIM_CK
LEFT JOIN DIM_MEMBER DMC ON DMC.MEMBER_DIM_CK = FC.MEMBER_DIM_CK 
INNER JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON DD.DATE_DIM_CK = FC.PRODUCT_DATE_DIM_CK 
INNER JOIN DIM_DATE DOB ON DOB.DATE_DIM_CK = DMC.BIRTH_DATE_DIM_CK 
WHERE FC.PRODUCT_NBR IN (SELECT * FROM TBL_PRODUCT)
AND FILL_DATE between 202001 and 202002
AND MEM_AGE = '18+'
ORDER BY FIRST_NAME
```

-- Questions: 
    ---COUNT HOW MANY PRODUCT IS ASSOCIATED TO A MEMBER VIA THE PRODUCT NUMBER
    ---WANT TO SUM UP THE COUNT OF THE UNIQUE PRODUCT  NBRS FOR EACH MEMBER(MBR_NBR) 
    ---THEN ADD A YTD FOR EACH SUMMED COUNT OF PRODUCT FOR MEMBER For each new month(Fill_Date)

Comment: I want to add two new fields, Product_Count, YTD_Product_Count where Product_Count will be the distinct count of Product_NBR summed, and YTD_Product_Count will be the YTD total

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on how to efficiently do this?

Comment: The two new fields you want are: 1) total # unique products per member, 2) YTD # products per member, per month (`FILL_DATE`)?  Does the YTD have to be a count of unique products or can it be total products?

Comment: The Ytd is the total product occurrence each month for the member

Comment: YTD (Year-to-date) typically means to include everything from the beginning of the year up until a given point in time.  Is this what you want?  Or do you just want a simple total for each month?  If it's the latter, then that would simplify my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it, but this may do the trick:

```sql
SELECT 
  src.mem_nbr, 
  MAX(src.first_name) AS first_name,
  MAX(src.last_name) AS last_name,
  MAX(src.product_desc) AS product_desc,
  src.year_month AS fill_date, 
  MAX(src.cum_cnt_yearly) AS ytd_per_month,
  MAX(uc.uniq_prd_cnt) AS uniq_prd_cnt
FROM (
  SELECT dmc.mem_nbr, dd.year_month, dmc.first_name, dmc.last_name, p.product_desc,
    CASE 
      WHEN CAST ((CURRENT_DATE - dob.date_date) / 365.25 AS INTEGER) >= 18  THEN '18+' 
      ELSE 'Less than 18' 
    END AS mem_age,
    COUNT(fc.product_nbr) OVER(
      PARTITION BY dmc.mem_nbr, <dd.year>
      ORDER BY dd.year_month
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) cum_cnt_yearly -- cumulative yearly row count
  FROM ft_product_claim fc -- product claims
  LEFT JOIN dim_product p ON fc.product_dim_ck = p.product_dim_ck -- product
  LEFT JOIN dim_member dmc ON dmc.member_dim_ck = fc.member_dim_ck -- member
  INNER JOIN dim_date dd ON dd.date_dim_ck = fc.product_date_dim_ck -- prod date
  INNER JOIN dim_date dob ON dob.date_dim_ck = dmc.birth_date_dim_ck -- birth date
  INNER JOIN tbl_product pd ON fc.product_nbr = pd.<prod_nbr> -- valid product
  WHERE year_month BETWEEN 202001 AND 202002
  AND mem_age = '18+'
) src
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT dmc.mem_nbr, COUNT(DISTINCT fc.product_nbr) uniq_prd_cnt
  FROM ft_product_claim fc -- product claims
  INNER JOIN dim_member dmc ON fc.member_dim_ck = dmc.member_dim_ck -- member info
  GROUP BY dmc.mem_nbr
) uc ON src.mem_nbr = uc.mem_nbr -- unique count
GROUP BY src.mem_nbr, src.fill_date;
```

This assumes:

- you want to get a count of the rows in `ft_product_claim`
- all your joins are 1-1 joins
- `tbl_product` has a matching `<prod_nbr>` field
- `dim_date` has a `<dd.year>` field, otherwise you'd have to use an expression to extract it

A couple observations:

1. You should never use a `SELECT *` unless you need all the fields, and in this case you don't; I don't even know if it would work as-is.  I converted `WHERE FC.PRODUCT_NBR IN (...)` to an `INNER JOIN`.
2. If you know you'll always have a matching row in `dim_product` and `dim_member`, change those joins to `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: did you forget to close something " uc ON src.mem_nbr = "

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I updated it.  Did this work?

Comment: Yeah it worked as is still have to do some refinement thank you!

Comment: Great!  Happy to help :)